# Apple watch series 3 or series 5 for development device?

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, watchos

I wish to start developing apps for the apple watch and I wonder if I can get just the series 3 model without cellular capability as the series 5 is a little too pricey for me. What am I missing if I don't get the series 5 and cellular capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Series 3 should be fine since the important part is that you'll have a physical device to test on. The Series 4 and Series 5 have rounded corners, more space on the display, and a bottom region outside of the [safe area](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_elements/building_watchos_app_interfaces_using_the_storyboard/supporting_multiple_watch_sizes). Just make sure the 40mm and 44mm sizes are also tested in Simulator or SwiftUI previews.

Comment: Hey there, I ended up buying a Series 5 as the store in my area don't stock up Series 3 units anymore. Anyway, thanks for your answer.